# Ubuntu harddisk formatting failed

Tags: partitioning

This is the problem I'm facing. Can any one suggest a solution

```
Error setting partition type after formatting: Error setting partition flags on /dev/sda2: Error spawning command-line `sgdisk --typecode 2:"ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7" "/dev/sda"': Failed to execute child process "sgdisk" (No such file or directory) (g-exec-error-quark, 8) (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

How to fix this ?

Comment: what did you try to format ubuntu?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install gdisk
```

---

This works because, while the error message the OP cited says a number of things, the key part is:

> Failed to execute child process "sgdisk" (No such file or directory)

So, assuming the issue is that sgdisk is not installed, it can be installed via the `gdisk` package. It worked for me.

Comment: Can you explain the repository you are asking the OP to install?

Comment: The error message the OP cited says a number of things, but this is the key part:

Failed to execute child process "sgdisk" (No such file or directory)

So, assuming the issue is that sgdisk is not installed, it can be installed via the gdisk package.  It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu on the hard disk, then it can cause many problems (because the disk is in use I suppose).

I would recommend using a Live CD/USB in this case. And the program that I often use is GParted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command, it worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install cryptsetup
```

By default `cryptsetup` is not installed during Ubuntu installation, and that package is required to open encrypted partitions.

Comment: Why did it worked? Can you state the reason why installing `cryptsetup` would work in this situation?